# Difference between gossamer and web

Tags: meaning

Is any difference between words `gossamer` and `web` in their meaninig?

Which word better describes this image?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image shows a spider web.

When baby spiders leave the egg, they make a very thin silk thread. The wind blows this and carries the baby spider to a new place. In the early morning of late summer the grass can be covered with these very fine threads, this is gossamer.

The webs that spiders make for catching flies should not be called gossamer. However gossamer is a rather rare thing to see, and many people call spider-webs covered in dew "gossamer" when they want to use a rarer or more impressive word. Many of the images of "gossamer" in a web search actually show "spider webs covered in dew".

You should not call that thing "gossamer" but many people do.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a difference.

*Gossamer* is the fine silk material used by the spider to *make* a web.

A *Web* is the finished product. So, "web" best describes the picture, although it may also be referred to as a "cobweb" or a "spider's web".

Note that "gossamer" can also mean other kinds of fine silk.

Also, the material used to make a web can be referred to as *webbing*.

Answer (score 1):

**gossamer** to the average speaker (of American English at least), the so-called "man on the street", is a textile. The word is perceived as a rather "poetic" term when describing a spider's web or a butterfly's wings.

Answer (score 1):

Per the OED, *gossamer* is "a fine filmy substance, consisting of cobwebs, spun by small spiders, which is seen floating in the air in calm weather, esp. in autumn, or spread over a grassy surface".

[A field coated in gossamer.](https://www.nhm.ac.uk/content/dam/nhmwww/discover/spider-webs/field-coated-in-gossamer-threads-baby-hero.jpg)

Comment: You've answered about a third of the question- can you also define _web_, and then explain what the difference is?

Comment: +1 A picture is worth a thousand words

Answer (score 0):

gossamer = light and delicate.

web = structure.

You can have a "gossamer web", but a web made of heavy ropes — that would not be considered *gossamer*, but still a *web*.